# Getter and property with the same name in object literal runs successfully although it is forbidden by documentation

Tags: javascript, object

I learnt the following from the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Description).

> Note the following when working with the get syntax:
>
> - It can have an identifier which is either a number or a string;
> - It must have exactly zero parameters (see Incompatible ES5 change: literal getter and setter functions must now have exactly zero or one arguments for more information);
> - It must not appear in an object literal with another get or with a data entry for the same property ({ get x() { }, get x() { } } and { x: ..., get x() { } } are forbidden).

I wrote the following code to test the third point.

```
var foo = {
    bar: 10,
    get bar() {
        return 20
    },
}

// The following call alerts 20.
alert(foo.bar)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46ejunuk/)

Here I have an object literal `obj` with a getter `obj.bar` with property name `bar` same as another property `bar` . This code should be forbidden as per the third point of the documentation I have quoted above. However, with Firefox 39.0, I see that this code runs fine and alerts 2. Why does this code run successfully when it is forbidden by the Mozilla documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction that MDN outlines for a getter

> It must not appear in an object literal with another get or with a data entry for the same property (`{ get x() { }, get x() { } }` and `{ x: ..., get x() { } }` are forbidden).

is not outlined in the actual [language spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5):

> The production `PropertyAssignment : get PropertyName ( ) { FunctionBody }` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `propName` be the result of evaluating `PropertyName`.
> 2. Let `closure` be the result of creating a new Function object as specified in [13.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2) with an empty parameter list and body specified by `FunctionBody`. Pass in the [LexicalEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) of the running execution context as the `Scope`. Pass in `true` as the `Strict` flag if the `PropertyAssignment` is contained in [strict code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1) or if its `FunctionBody` is [strict code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1).
> 3. Let `desc` be the `[Property Descriptor][5]{[[Get]]: closure, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true}`
> 4. Return `[Property Identifier][5] (propName, desc)`.

Therefore it seems there is no such restriction, it might be that the MDN article is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. nodejs chucks it out:

```
C:\Dev\javascript\so-flow-32206528.js:6
    get bar() {
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Object literal may not have data and accessor property
with the same name
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

The MDN docs do seem to contradict the implementation.